# How to correctly compile C app for 64 bits with CUDA 5 and Glib on Windows?

Tags: c, compilation, cuda, 64-bit, glib

i'm trying to compile a project on VS2010 for 64 bits wrote in C and use CUDA 5.0 and GLib. I already had a working profile for 32 bits and everything goes ok.

On configuration manager i created a new context for 64 bits with settings copied from the 32 bits one. Then, i updated Glib paths for 64 bits version and had set  CUDA C/C++-> Target Machine Platform to "64 bit".

Well, it compiles ok, but when i try to run get the error:

```
The application couldn't be initialized correctly (0x000007b).
```

Am i forgeting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a missing library.

Recent versions of Windows just give that generic message instead of a detailed message about which libraries were not found. There's also a difference in which information is provided when starting the app from the command line and starting it from Explorer.

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will tell you which libraries are missing.

Comment: Thank you. Depency Walker told me that my VS was using the 32 bits GLib dll. I corrected that, but now looks like i don't have libintl-8.dll, and it's a dependency from glib. I had a look at Gnome's FTP but didn't find a link for download it =/

Comment: Nvm. Just found it inside gettext runtime package : http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/dependencies/gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win64.zip . Thank you =)